# Code reusing with anonymous class in Java

Tags: java, code-reuse, anonymous-class

Java 7

I have the following interface:

```
public interface SqlOperator{

    public String apply(Object o);

    /**
    * @return an operator representing the set defined 
    * by inversing the image of {@this operator}.
    */
    public SqlOperator not();

    //Some other methods
}
```

And I have a few its implementations that look like:

```
public class Foo implements SqlOperator{

    public SqlOperator not(){
        return new Foo(){
            @Override
            public String apply(Object o){
                return String.format("NOT (%s)", super.apply(o));
            }
        };
    }

    //other methods implementation
}
```

and this

```
public class Bar implements SqlOperator{

    public SqlOperator not(){
        return new Bar(){
            @Override
            public String apply(Object o){
                return String.format("NOT (%s)", super.apply(o));
            }
        };
    }

    //other methods implementation
}
```

The thing is the `not()` method is pretty much the same for all implementation for now (Currently I have 7 ones) except the class to be instantiated with the `new` operator. Is there a way to avoid wiritng such boilerplate code any time I need to implement the `SqlOperator`.

Comment: what java version are you using?

Comment: Can I suggest that `not(foo)` would be a better API than `foo.not()` - it would be better to use composition to build up your expression. It also makes implementing `and` or `or` operators easier: `and(foo, bar)` rather than `foo.and(bar)` etc. This means that your `SqlOperator` interface would contain simply the `apply` method.

Comment: @AndyTurner Well, I thought about it. But the not method is operator-specific.

Answer (score 3):

In pre-Java-8 times the standard option was to create an abstract class like `AbstractSqlOperator implements SqlOperator` which defines methods having some standard implementation. Then concrete implementations extend this abstract class rather than implement the interface directly.

Java-8 introduced a new way to do this using default methods:

```
public interface SqlOperator{

    public String apply(Object o);

    /**
    * @return an operator representing the set defined 
    * by inversing the image of {@this operator}.
    */
    default public SqlOperator not() {
        return new SqlOperator(){
            @Override
            public String apply(Object o){
                return String.format("NOT (%s)", SqlOperator.this.apply(o));
            }

            @Override
            public SqlOperator not() {
                // double not: just return the original operator
                return SqlOperator.this;
            }
        };
    }

    //Some other methods
}
```

Comment: Well, the interface doesn't know about `SomeImplementation`.

Comment: @St.Antario, it can implement itself. See the updated answer

Comment: Want you have the Stack Exception ? as you cal apply from apply ?

Comment: @DamianLeszczyński-Vash, I call apply for the different object (outer instance). Try, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your SqlOperator interface in an abstract class. Then let your SomeImplementation classes inherit from the abstract class. The abstract class will implement the interface not() method.

```
public abstract class AbstractImplementation implements SqlOperator
{
    public SqlOperator not(){
    return new SomeImplementation(){
        @Override
        public String apply(Object o){
            return String.format("NOT (%s)", super.apply(o));
        }
    };
}

//...
public class SomeImplementation extends AbstractImplementation
{
    //... your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have plenty of options.

If you're on Java8, you can create a *default* method within the `SqlOperator` interface and there will be no need to implement it across the subclasses:

```
public interface SqlOperator{
    public default SqlOperator not() {
        return new SomeImplementation(){
            @Override
            public String apply(Object o){
                return String.format("NOT (%s)", super.apply(o));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

However, if you still haven't upgraded to Java8, then you could just introduce an `abstract` subclass of `SqlOperator` where you will have the `not()` implementation and then all the other implementors could extend this abstract class. For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractSqlOperator implements SqlOperator {
    public SqlOperator not() {
        return new SomeImplementation(){
            @Override
            public String apply(Object o){
                return String.format("NOT (%s)", super.apply(o));
            }
        };
    }
}

public class SomeImplementation extends AbstractSqlOperator { ... }
```

Comment: Couldn't you look at the updated question? I believe I wasn't clear about what I actually wanted...

Comment: Yup. Then the approach with the `abstract` class, which contains the shared `not()` implementation will suite for your case.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you have some design issue, as you clone the code. Already presented solution base on inheritance i would rather go in composition.

The goal is to crate a SqlOperator that negate other operator.

I would remove the not() from SqlOperator interface. Each operator should be separated. `NOT`,`LIKE`, `AND`, `OR` are the operators used in SQL that operate on expression. Naturally an operator AND should do not know how to negate it.

```
public interface SqlOperator{
    public String apply(Object o);
}

class NotOperator implements SqlOperator {

    private final SqlOperator operator;

    NotOperator(SqlOperator operator) {
       this.operator = operator;
    }

    public String apply(Object o) {
        return String.format("NOT (%s)", operator.apply(o));
    }

}
```